# How to find small short programming freelance job or project

Tags: freelance-websites

I would like to become a freelancing programmer and web developer. I am now studying computer science in university, so my programming skills and the number of language that I know will improve and increase over the times. Since I am still studying, I would like to find some small short programming or web development freelance job to do. But some freelancing website I found on the web requires bidding, or the jobs are long term.
I would like if someone can recommend some freelance website for small programming or web development projects.
And also, is there any tips for getting started in freelancing?
Thanks

Comment: see the multitude of similar questions elsewhere on the site, http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-i-get-my-first-job-at-a-freelancing-site?rq=1, http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/871/how-do-i-start-my-own-freelancing-company?rq=1, etc.

Comment: @user3244085 Freelancing SE would really benefit from a canonical question & answer for this due to the multiple questions on the topic. One that also aims to address a wide range of starting points, as I rarely see pro-bono, charitable or open source suggestions from answers, for complete beginners who still want to scope out their skills and abilities. Also many don't fully address the difficulty of getting a first freelancing project, they may touch upon it with "I've been in this situation and understand . . ." but tend not to provide solid, useful tips on overcoming the difficulty.

Comment: Fiverr, UpWork...

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of thing I suppose you will still looking and looking and probably won't find anything at all, I use freelancer.com and there was a few months I was looking for small jobs that I can finish in less than 15 days but didn't work, my best advice is: Start a small project yourself while still looking, as is web I'm not that familiar with it, but I'm mainly a mobile dev and when I can't find a freelancer job I continue my project or start a new one if I'm free, Even if they don't get to the market it works as an experience & learning ways of improvements of my coding skills, and platform I'm developing in. This can help you to speed up any medium/large project that you may get because you already have a design :D.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous topics about this all over Internet.

Short-term options:

- Ask friends and family if you can help them in some way by developing web app for their need
- Ask fellow students that aren't doing so well to help them with their studies for a fee
- Offer web development tuition services in local classifieds
- Go through web development forums and search for a topic with no good answers and then offer to solve a problem for a fee

Long-term options:

- Make profile on freelancing sites such as UpWork, Freelancer, Fiverr etc... and be active in applying for jobs and improving your profile (this can take months)
- Make online portfolio with links to your previous work and recommendations of previous clients (letters with links to their LinkedIn profile or even better link to YouTube video in which your clients recommend you)
- Write a professional blog (post about web development and similar) and promote it any way you can all the time
- Comment on other developers's blogs
- Comment on web development forums and portals (don't forget to include link to your blog, especially to service page)
- Ask previous clients to recommend you
- If you don't have any experience then **ask to volunteer on a project that you think would be a good reference**

Answer (score 0):

I'm editing the answer because the comment below asked me to.  When it comes to programming as a freelance career you've come to the right place to get answers and resources on how to earn a living.  What I would like to do is point you in the direction where many people have succeeded in finding exactly what it is you're looking for.  Try:
freelancer.com
upwork.com
guru.com
djangojobs.com
linkedin.com
truelancer.com

When you bid for projects don't get discouraged if you don't at first succeed.  Rememeber, it takes time to build a reputation for good programming skills.
Let us know how you get along with your search.  Good luck.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/5736)

Comment: In this case, the answer is the link.  I've seen many questions here on finding resources; most questions (not answers) were flagged or marked for deletion.  I find it surprising that my precise and useful answer was not enough before the edit.