# How to find Web Development work outside the freelancing sites?

Tags: outsourcing, sales

I am freelancer from over 2 years but I can't get the projects more than 7, from various freelancing sites.
I want to know that which are other ways through I can directly contact the clients, who outsources their web development work. Specially from UK, USA, Australia and Others...
How can big companies get the work?

Thank You.

Comment: Very similar: http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/221/best-approach-to-finding-clients-in-your-own-city/223#223

Answer (score 4):

You can get work on different forums which deal with web development. All of them will have job sections where people look for programmers there, rather than on freelancing sites. But you need to have reputation there, too.

Big companies do not go to forums. Big companies do not go to freelancing sites. Big companies will very very rarely hire a freelancer; they have larger projects and need a team.

You should aim for individual clients or smaller companies; you will not get million-dollar project, but you will be able to earn 2 or 3 times your regular salary just by accommodating those clients.

Remember, all money you earn goes into your pockets. There is not a middle man (aka a boss) who will take the big money and leave you the crumbs.

In all my career I've only managed to get one large company, by accidentally working for a CEO who liked my work. And I really see this as luck; do not expect such offers in the future, as they're rare.

Answer (score 2):

The crux of this question is really "how do I market my business?"

Marketing and advertising are probably the bane of all small-business owners (and as a freelancer, you are a small business owner). First, you need to have your own website; and it has to look *good*. Second, you need to fork out some money for standard advertising methods - google/yahoo/bing/facebook ads, newspaper, phonebook, etc.

But what is going to cost you the most time and effort, but will likely bring the best results, is for you to go out and *find* customers yourself, instead of waiting for them to find you. Browse around the web and find really crappy looking websites and contact the owners with a pitch. Network with friends, relatives, and associates to give out your business information when they meet someone who needs a website. Walk down the street and stop at every business and give them a business card and a sales pitch. These won't be huge corporate jobs, but as Peter MV already said, those jobs have full-time dedicated internal developers.

All of this hinges on you having something excellent to display and demonstrate your skills. Your own website should be the pinnacle of your skills. You should have a portfolio of previous websites that demonstrates your flexibility, adaptability, and design variety. You should have a simple but attention-getting business card to give to all of your clients so they can recommend you through word-of-mouth advertising. And I recommend that you do not try to search for business too far outside of your local area - the competition gets tougher, the pay get lower, and the taxes get higher. If you *are* going to pursue international customers, make sure you are *fluent* in the language where you are marketing.